# Arch Linux 64 bit - Will not wake from pm-suspend

Tags: arch-linux, power-management, suspend

Alright, I've been messing with this off and on for the past few months.  pm-suspend used to work fine; I recently upgraded most of my hardware, and even then it worked fine.  At some point there must have been an update that broke things; since then I have either been unable to suspend, or unable to wake from suspend.  Recently I have gotten suspend-to-ram working with pm-utils, but now it will not wake.

When I do a `pm-suspend` everything seems to suspend fine.  However, when I try to wake the machine back up (generally by pushing the power button), the machine turns on, but I get nothing on my screen, neither of my monitors get any output, and I cannot ping my pc from my laptop, so I do not think it is even booting.  I will post logs, if anything else would be helpful, I can post those as well.

Note: I do have two video cards, one that I used for passthrough to a qemu machine (my AMD card) and one that I use for the host.

Kernel:

```
4.11.3-1-ARCH
```

/etc/pm/config.d/modules:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="xhci_hcd igb vfio-pci igb xhci_pci ahci"
```

pm-suspend.log (seems to indicate it suspended correctly).

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Sat Jun  3 15:40:41 EDT 2017: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/00Radeon suspend suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/00Radeon suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux machinename 4.11.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 28 10:40:17 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
amdgpu               1507328  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  2
nvidia_drm             45056  0
uinput                 20480  2
nvidia_modeset        798720  1 nvidia_drm
iptable_filter         16384  0
snd_usb_audio         167936  0
btusb                  40960  0
snd_usbmidi_lib        24576  1 snd_usb_audio
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd-_hda_codec_realtek    73728  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
nvidia              11476992  1 nvidia_modeset
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_rawmidi
mousedev               20480  0
bluetooth             487424  5 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
evdev                  24576  2
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
mac_hid                16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
amdkfd                118784  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
intel_rapl             20480  0
arc4                   16384  2
radeon               1470464  0
edac_core              45056  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
ttm                    86016  2 amdgpu,radeon
intel_cstate           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  0
iwlmvm                286720  0
drm_kms_helper        126976  3 amdgpu,radeon,nvidia_drm
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_hda_codec         106496  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
pcspkr                 16384  0
drm                   299008  6 amdgpu,radeon,ttm,nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_core           65536  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
snd_pcm                90112  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
igb                   192512  0
e1000e                225280  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_i801               24576  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65536  12 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
dca                    16384  1 igb
iwlwifi               192512  1 iwlmvm
mei_me                 36864  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  3 igb,amdgpu,radeon
soundcore              16384  1 snd
ptp                    20480  2 igb,e1000e
mei                    86016  1 mei_me
pps_core               16384  1 ptp
lpc_ich                24576  0
shpchp                 32768  0
wmi                    20480  1 mxm_wmi
sch_fq_codel           20480  4
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
tpm                    40960  2 tpm_tis,tpm_tis_core
fuse                   98304  1
button                 16384  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxdrv               385024  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
tun                    28672  0
sg                     36864  0
b43                   397312  0
bcma                   49152  1 b43
mac80211              696320  2 iwlmvm,b43
cfg80211              520192  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,b43,mac80211
nfsd                  319488  13
ssb                    61440  1 b43
auth_rpcgss            57344  1 nfsd
mmc_core              122880  2 b43,ssb
oid_registry           16384  1 auth_rpcgss
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsd
lockd                  86016  1 nfsd
rfkill                 20480  3 bluetooth,cfg80211
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
led_class              16384  3 iwlmvm,b43,input_leds
rng_core               16384  1 b43
sunrpc                282624  19 auth_rpcgss,nfsd,nfs_acl,lockd
pcmcia                 53248  1 ssb
pcmcia_core            20480  1 pcmcia
ip_tables              24576  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               28672  2 ip_tables,iptable_filter
ext4                  528384  5
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
jbd2                   90112  1 ext4
fscrypto               24576  1 ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
algif_skcipher         20480  0
af_alg                 16384  1 algif_skcipher
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 45056  0
hid                   110592  2 hid_generic,usbhid
dm_crypt               28672  2
dm_mod                102400  17 dm_crypt
sd_mod                 45056  5
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                28672  1 ahci
xhci_pci               16384  0
aesni_intel           163840  4
ehci_pci               16384  0
libata                208896  2 ahci,libahci
xhci_hcd              184320  1 xhci_pci
ehci_hcd               73728  1 ehci_pci
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
usbcore               208896  9 usbhid,snd_usb_audio,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,snd_usbmidi_lib,btusb,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
cryptd                 20480  5 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
scsi_mod              155648  3 sd_mod,libata,sg
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
serio                  20480  0
kvm_intel             192512  0
kvm                   528384  1 kvm_intel
virtio_net             36864  0
virtio_pci             24576  0
virtio_blk             20480  0
virtio_ring            20480  3 virtio_blk,virtio_net,virtio_pci
virtio                 16384  3 virtio_blk,virtio_net,virtio_pci
vfio_pci               40960  0
vfio_virqfd            16384  1 vfio_pci
irqbypass              16384  2 kvm,vfio_pci
vfio_iommu_type1       24576  0
vfio                   24576  2 vfio_iommu_type1,vfio_pci
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       65900412      313716    65401364        2368      185332    65025768
Swap:      16383996           0    16383996

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01grub suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01grub suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-xhci_hcd suspend suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-xhci_hcd suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49bluetooth suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49bluetooth suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55wicd suspend suspend:
Unable to connect to wicd daemon - is it running?

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55wicd suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
Unloading kernel module xhci_hcd...Done.
Unloading kernel module igb...Done.
Unloading kernel module vfio-pci...Done.
Unloading kernel module igb...Done.
Unloading kernel module xhci_pci...Done.
Unloading kernel module ahci...modprobe: FATAL: Module ahci is in use.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/functions: line 89: log: command not found
Failed.
Unloading kernel module xhci_hcd...Done.
Unloading kernel module xhci_hcd...Done.
Unloading kernel module igb...Done.
Unloading kernel module vfio-pci...Done.
Unloading kernel module igb...Done.
Unloading kernel module xhci_pci...Done.
Unloading kernel module ahci...modprobe: FATAL: Module ahci is in use.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/functions: line 89: log: command not found
Failed.
Unloading kernel module xhci_hcd...Done.

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 3

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.
Sat Jun  3 15:40:42 EDT 2017: performing suspend
```

lspci -k

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DMI2 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f00
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:03.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Map/VTd_Misc/System Management (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f28
00:05.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO Hot Plug (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f29
00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO RAS/Control Status/Global Errors (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f2a
00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D I/O APIC (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f2c
00:11.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset SPSR (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d7c
00:11.4 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset sSATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d62
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d31
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset MEI Controller #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d3a
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 15a1
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d2d
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1159
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d26
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d47
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset 6-Port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d02
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 8d22
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao XT / Trinidad XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370X]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3030
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device aab0
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 6251
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
04:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fb9 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 6251
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1539
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
08:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
ff:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f81
ff:0b.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f36
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:0b.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link 0/1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f37
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R3 QPI Link Debug (rev 01)
ff:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe0
ff:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe1
ff:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe2
ff:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe3
ff:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe4
ff:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe5
ff:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6ff8
ff:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6ff9
ff:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe0
ff:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe0
ff:0f.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Caching Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fe0
ff:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R2PCIe Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f1d
ff:10.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D R2PCIe Agent (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f34
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f1e
ff:10.6 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f7d
ff:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Ubox (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f1f
ff:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fa0
ff:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f30
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fa8
ff:13.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f71
ff:13.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6faa
ff:13.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fab
ff:13.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fac
ff:13.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fad
ff:13.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast (rev 01)
ff:13.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 01)
ff:14.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fb0
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:14.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fb1
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:14.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 0 Error (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fb2
ff:14.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 1 Error (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fb3
ff:14.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
ff:14.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
ff:14.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
ff:14.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 0/1 Interface (rev 01)
ff:15.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 2 Thermal Control (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fb4
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:15.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 3 Thermal Control (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fb5
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:15.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 2 Error (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fb6
ff:15.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 0 - Channel 3 Error (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fb7
ff:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Target Address/Thermal/RAS (rev 01)
ff:16.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast (rev 01)
ff:16.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 01)
ff:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Memory Controller 1 - Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: bdx_uncore
ff:17.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
ff:17.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
ff:17.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
ff:17.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DDRIO Channel 2/3 Interface (rev 01)
ff:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f98
ff:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f99
ff:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f9a
ff:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6fc0
ff:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 6f9c
ff:1f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
ff:1f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Power Control Unit (rev 01)
```